# extracting user info from SQLLITE3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, label

I am creating a banking GUI using python and SQLLITE3.

At this point in the code, the user has logged in. I am trying to display the information associated with the user. Every username is unique--so here I am attempting to get the name that is associated with "user_name2" which is just the username that had been previously used to login. It returns a cursor object. How can I get it to simply print the value into my GUI?

```
get_name = cur.execute(f"SELECT name FROM all_accounts WHERE username = '{user_name2}'")

Label(user_info, text=f"Name:{get_name}", font="times 13").grid(row=0, sticky=NW, pady=10, padx=30)
```

Comment: What is the value of ```get_name``` after that ```cur.execute(...)``` line?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer

```py
cur.execute(f"SELECT name FROM all_accounts WHERE username = '{user_name2}'")
name = cur.fetchone()
if not name is None:
    Label(user_info, text=f"Name:{name}", font="times 13").grid(row=0, sticky=NW, pady=10, padx=30)
else:
    print("No user found!")
```

### Security WARNING

If you do not filter `user_name2`, bad guys will conduct SQL injection attack to your database. You can consult [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders)

The simplest method is using plaecholder, which is very easy in python

```py
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM all_accounts WHERE username = ?", user_name2)
name = cur.fetchone()
if not name is None:
    Label(user_info, text=f"Name:{name}", font="times 13").grid(row=0, sticky=NW, pady=10, padx=30)
else:
    print("No user found!")
```

Comment: instead of `if not name is None:` you could use `if name:` - it will be more readable.

Comment: very helpful. much appreciated